# OSX Sierra Notes & Reminders sync disabled

Tags: icloud, macos, notes.app

On all my other devices(iPhone, iPad, another Macbook) I am able to sync my iCloud notes just fine. For some reason my work's Macbook on Sierra is unable to sync and the checkbox is completely disabled. Any ideas of how I can get around this?

[image]

Comment: Is this locked-down from your company?  Also, are you using the same Apple ID on all the devices?

Comment: Same Apple ID. Find My Mac has always been locked down but on El Capitan I was able to sync just fine. I suppose it's possible the company upped their game and blocked these apps for Sierra. I can't see any reason behind blocking a productivity apps from syncing though.

Comment: Usually, I only see these setting disabled if something is blocking their access.  If you log into iCloud.com with the same Apple ID does it work (probably will because it works on your other devices but it's worth a check)?  Also, have you tried logging out and back in to iCloud on this machine?

Answer (score 1):

Check for a MacOS update, if you have one do it. If not then continue below.

---

Does your work MacBook have any work-installed profiles in your system preferences?

A lot of times companies don't allow certain features to be accessed. If there is a profile or a preference there that isnt a default preference then it was installed.

If you don't have any profiles or special preferences then I would check to see if you can access www.icloud.com and see if you can visit the site on your work MacBook. If you can then great, if not then its likely that the server is blocked, which means that it is either blocked from the network.

If none of the above apply, then there are 2 things that you can do to test and see if its a software issue.

1. Sign out of iCloud and then sign back in and see if the issue continues.
2. Try it in safe mode to see if there is something else that could be preventing it.
3. Create a new user account on that MacBook and sign into iCloud with the same Apple ID account. See if the issue continues.

If they still don't work with either of those troubleshooting steps then you need to backup the Mac with Time Machine and then the next step is to re-install MacOS and then once its been installed, try it again. It should work if none of the above did.